# CSS3 Transition animation when another div is removed

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a `<div>` that contains notifications. So my markup is similar to this:

```
<div id="notifications">
    <div class="notification">
         .... <!-- Notification 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="notification">
         .... <!-- Notification 2 -->
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I can animate the `notification` divs as they come in and out. But say I were to close notification 1 (remove it from my DOM), then naturally notification 2 will just jump to notification 1's position.

Would it be possible to animate this using css? I know very little about UI coding. Is it possible to say through CSS3 "Whenever you need to move, for whatever reason, do it smoothly over 1 second", or must I hard code the size of the notifications and use `translate` or something?

Comment: You can if you change the first's height, preferably using `transform:scaleY()` for performance but this warps it but animating height is expensive. If they were positioned absolutely then you could. As it is you pretty much have to use javascript to do this well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it if your divs are of similar height.

The key is to animate the margin height of the first item in the list.

```
.test {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.notification {
    height: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 2px;
}

.notification:first-child {
    -webkit-animation: move 1s ease-out;
    animation: move 1s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {margin-top: 42px;}
   100% {margin-top: 2px;}
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {margin-top: 42px;}
   100% {margin-top: 2px;}
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88Cw4/)

In the demo there is a little drawback, that is that the first time it is rendered, the animation also plays. In production, that won't probably be an issue because the list will be empty at the beginning.

A better solution that solves the previous issue:

CSS

```
.notifications {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px green;
    padding-top: 40px;
    transition: padding-top 1s;
}

.notifications:empty {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.notification {
    height: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 2px;
    transition: margin-top 1s;
}

.notification:first-child {
    margin-top: -38px;
}
```

I have noticed that I was using animations, but that transitions was enough. Besides that the main issue: avoid the transition when I am adding an element to the empty container. The way to solve that is to create the opposite transition in the container element. See the property set via CSS to the .notifications:empty.

It is a little awkward because padding won't support negative values; that implies doing the opposite of what would have been natural, and changing also the margins in the notification side.

[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88Cw4/1/)

Comment: "In the demo there is a little drawback, that is that the first time it is rendered, the animation also plays. In production, that won't probably be an issue because the list will be empty at the beginning."

The problem is that when the list is empty and I add one notification, the animation runs on the first one I add, so the notification appears, then jumps down and easesOut into its original place.

Comment: You are right, I under estimated the problem. Added a better solution

Comment: If the height is set, you could transition the height of an appended element to the set height. Otherwise you might just add an opacity fade in when a new item is added to make it look smoother (: Great work, vals!